# What's with this ghostly tooltip in the Grid dropdowns? (image included)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

This appears on all of the columns in my grid:

### Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m:

[image]

### Firefox 21.0:

[image]

All of the columns in my table look something like this:

```
{
    text: 'Audit Type',
    width: 100,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'requestType'
},
```

I have no idea what's causing this. The javascript console shows no errors about missing images either.

Any help that could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

### More info

I'm using Chrome Version 28.0.1500.72 m and Extjs 4.2.1.883

My app is run on my own computer... so a local server. I'm using Play Framework with Scala on my backend.

Comment: please tell us what browser you are using and also what version of extjs down to the minor revision, example 4.2.1.  Also if you are running your app on a local server or through the filesystem

Comment: Edited! Chrome Version 28.0.1500.72 m, Extjs 4.2.1.883, local server - I'm not completely sure what you mean by through the filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh what silliness.

I did this earlier:

```
    .x-panel {margin: 8em;}
```

This ended up moving the entire grid except for the menu shadows.

Giving the grid an `id` property in its definition and having this instead in my stylesheet solves the problem:

```
    #grid {margin: 8em;}
```